# Regex for root page path

Tags: regex

I have two URLs

```
/trip
/trip/1
/something
/something/1
```

I'm trying to find the regex that gets me /trip and /something (so not specifically /trip but anything that's in that root)

Here's what I got but it's only grabbing the first two characters for me.

`\/(.=?)\/?`

Comment: From the [regex tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info): "Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe,

```
^/[^/]+$
```

#### <sup>[RegEx Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/KWSYXr/1/)</sup>

or with a positive lookbehind,

```
(?<=^/)[^/]+$
```

#### <sup>[RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/2D2JcH/1/)</sup>

might simply work OK.

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/uSl3od/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/uSl3od/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]